# How do I properly install pads into a Shimano BR-M365 disk brake caliper?

Tags: brakes, shimano, disc-brake, brake-pads

I've been an idiot. I took them off the bike this morning, and there's nothing left - the springs have been bent back and stripped off, and that strange 'rubbing' noise I've heard from the back wheel? Yes, it was...

I've bought some new pads, but I don't want to mess things up any further.

How do I properly install pads into a Shimano BR-M365 disk brake caliper?

Any hints, clues, do and definitely don't?

Comment: The question is kinda vague, can you make several photos depicting the issue you are trying to resolve?

Comment: Does your bike have the same caliper on the front?   Consider CAREFULLY removing the pads from that and see how they go in.  Take photos as a reminder.  Do not squeeze the brake levers at all if there are no pads and the rotor is not between the pads.

Comment: Consider reading the packaging of the pads and make sure you're following the instructions.

Comment: Are you positive the new pads match the old pads in shape ?

Comment: There is a possibility that things have gone too far and the disc has been damaged by the pad substrate. The discs might be scored and inclined to wear new pads very fast. Keep an eye on this. The only solution at this point will be to buy a new disc (fairly cheap)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because you let your pads get too far worn down does not mean you are automatically going to screw up replacing them.

Hydraulic disc brake pad replacement is reasonably simple:

- Check you have the correct pads for the calipers.
- Look up Shimano's installation instructions. I just googled 'shimano BR-M365' and found the [product page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/altus-m2000/BR-M365.html). Pad installation instructions are in the [dealer manual](http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-MDBR001-03-ENG.pdf) found on that page.
- YouTube is replete with bike maintenance videos. Park Tool has a [excellent channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzaZ1sPWEuZN-I8_XT6AH8g), Global Cycling Network has some good maintenance videos, here is their [hydraulic pad replacement one](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzaZ1sPWEuZN-I8_XT6AH8g).
- The big 'don't' is do not pull the brake lever when the disc is not in the caliper, and *especially* don't do it when the pads are removed. The pistons will be pushed out to far and do not retract. They can be pushed back in to the caliper (you have to do this when installing the new pads), but over extending the pistons with no pads in the caliper can result in fluid leakage.

Comment: The pistons will not autoretract, but you will be able to push them back in using a tool like a tyre lever. You'll probably have to do this anyway given the pistons will have come out a fair way as the old pads wore down. A plastic tyre lever is safest but something with a wide head and no sharp edges like a metal spoon type lever would also work. Don't use something sharp like a screwdriver though.

Comment: Good point, I expanded the answer. Thx.